# can't send mail through SMTP

Tags: php, email, post, smtp, phpmailer

For some reason i can't send an email through my free web hosting. The web hosting service says SMTP is enabled but when i click the send button, it will just redirect me to a white blank page. There is no error code, its just a white page.
Tell me what's wrong in the code?
Suggestions will be appreciated.

P.S - input **required** also doesn't work, when i press the send button with every field empty, it still opens up send.php...

My html form :

```
<form action="send.php" method="POST">
            <div class="cdiv">
                <input name="name" class="info" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" required />
            </div>
            <div class="cdiv">
                <input name="email" class="info" type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email ID" required />
            </div>
            <div class="cdiv" style="height:75px;">
                <textarea name="message" class="info" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Your Message" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="sendbtn">SEND</button>
        </form>
```

my send.php :

```
<?php
$body = $_POST['message'];
$subject = 'Automated message';
$from = $_POST['email'];
$from_name = $_POST['name'];
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
require_once("class.smtp.php");
require_once("class.pop3.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->Username = "dhruv1103@gmail.com";  
$mail->Password = "password";           
$mail->SetFrom = $from;
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AddAddress = "dhruv1103@gmail.com";
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
    return false;
} else {
    $error = 'Message sent!';
    echo "Sent!";
    return true;
}
?>
```

Comment: Try to dump the $_POST variable on the send page. Is this shown?

Comment: When you use the minimal use of PHPMailer, you have to include the `class.smtp.php` too, else you cannot use SMTP. I would recommend you to just use the `PHPMailerAutoload.php`, as this will ease the pain of having to include all the files needed, if you ever need other settings from PHPMailer.

Comment: Try basing your code on [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) instead of using obsolete and buggy ones from elsewhere, and [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 1):

You have to require `class.smtp.php`too, right now you are only including the minimal of phpmailer, but to send mails with SMTP, you need to include SMTP too.

You can download it from their github [here.](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php)

For doing it all a lot more simpler, I would recomend you to use their autoloader instead, this way you don't have to require all the classes you need yourself, you will of course still have to download the required classes.

Answer (score 0):

add after

```
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
```

this

```
require_once 'class.smtp.php';
require_once 'class.pop3.php';
```

then you can replace
this line

```
$mail->SetFrom = $from;
```

by this

```
$mail->From     = $from;
$mail->FromName = $from_name;
```

And tell me what you get ?

I get just a blank page again...

Replace the send.php by this (don't forget your password)

```
require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
require_once 'class.smtp.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'dhruv1103@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'Your password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port     = 587;
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;


$mail->From     = $_POST['email'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];

$mail->addAddress('dhruv1103@gmail.com');


$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->Priority = 1;
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject  = 'Automated message';
$mail->Body     = $_POST['message'];
$mail->AltBody  = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
$mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';


if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Comment: Probably an error if OP doesn't have these files ;-)

Comment: sorry bad English, yes without the class.smtp.php, he can't send anything ;-)

Comment: @bfahmi, why are you requiring `class.pop3.php` too? He only needs smtp, as he is only sending mails through smtp.

Comment: I get the same blank page

Comment: @uruloke, you are right it's not important for sending

Comment: @programmingandroid, you can tested it in your localhost, if it's work, then the problem is with your web hosting

Comment: then what do i do? tell me ill make the changes.

Comment: how do i test in my localhost?

Comment: anyway, you can install server-web in your machine, if ubuntu you can try https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/lamp, and if windows you can try http://www.commentcamarche.net/contents/789-installation-de-easyphp

Comment: @programmingandroid, what you get ?

Comment: you can set $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; for view the problem and paste the result for debug, for note: you have the file class.smtp.php in your directory ?

Comment: @programmingandroid, replace the send.php with the code bellow, and it will works

Comment: in the answer above, sorry i said bellow :)

Comment: @programmingandroid, :)

Comment: Everyone up vote @bfahmi, he has given the correct solution above ^